# Mapbox - Images as Maps

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

In the past, by following [this tutorial](http://www.macwright.org/2012/08/13/images-as-maps.html) by Tom MacWright, I was able to in a few steps display any jpeg images as an interactive map with Mapbox.

The steps are summarized below:

1. Run a [python script](https://gist.github.com/tmcw/3326365) via the command line to convert a jpeg image to a GeoTIFF file.
2. Using what is now called Mapbox Studios Classic, I make a new layer with the aforementioned GeoTIFF and then upload it to Mapbox Editor.
3. From Mapbox Editor I can then add features like markers and polygons and other interactive elements to the custom image map.

Unfortunately, the second step now fails ever since the Mapbox Studios desktop app (now referred to as Mapbox Studios Classic) became superseded by Mapbox Studios the web app. I can no longer upload any of my converted GeoTIFFS, not even the sames that I uploaded without a problem in the past. Instead I get this error:

> Error: Error creating Mapnik Datasource: Invalid raster: Invalid pixelsize in geotransform array

I haven't the slightest clue what that means. Googling around hasn't turn up a single hint (or at least a hint I could recognize).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdal_translate params in python script must be:

`['gdal_translate', '-a_ullr', str(-w/2), str(h/2), str(w/2), str(-h/2), '-a_srs', MERC, infile, '%s.tif' % infile]`

(swap h/2 and -h/2)